# Randomizer function/global variables trouble in python?

Tags: python, global-variables

So I have some code that is being somewhat troublesome to rewrite:

```
def func_A():

    x=[]
    # the function picks random members of the local x and rearranges them,
    # after giving x some initial value
    return x
```

Now I want to create an iteration in a `func_B` such that, for each run-through in an interation, `func_B` uses the `x` value that `func_A` generates to do things.

However, I want to avoid making `x` a global variable.

My first thought was to make the first line of the def of `func_B` `x=func_A()`, but this would run the randomizer twice and the value of `x` would be changed.

How do I reference the same `x` that `func_A` produces in `func_B` without running the randomizer again (until the next iteration in `func_B`) and without using global variables?

Comment: You mean without passing `x` as an a parameter between the functions?

Comment: Yes, passing as a parameter would seem to be the obvious solution - what's the reason you can't do that?

Comment: Why do you need to generate `x` outside of `func_B` if you want a new `x` every time you call `func_B`? Are you doing something with it outside `func_B`?

Comment: Joel + Daniel...I am looking to pass x as a parameter, but how would I do that in the code without running func_A again?

Comment: @AkshatShekhar Because this question is very vague you should explain why the two given answers are not acceptable. We still don't know what you want apparantly

Comment: I want to use x in func_B without directly using it as an argument or making it global. I want some kind of "carrier" that func_A delivers its finished x to and from which func_B can retrieve x, without that carrier being the global namespace and without that retrieval requiring calling func_A again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Classes

```
import random
class Randomizer():
    def __init__(self):
        # Generates a list of random values
        self.x = []
        self.rng = 10
        for i in range(1,self.rng+1):
            self.x.append(random.random())            

        # Need to call once to make sure all vars defined
        self.func_A()

    # pick a random value from a list
    def func_A(self):
        self.recent = self.x[random.randint(0,self.rng-1)]
        return self.recent

    # Do something with random value picked by A
    def func_B(self):
        return self.recent*self.recent
```

Think this is what you meant?

```
>>> r = Randomizer()
>>> r.func_A()
0.91223345147715629
>>> r.func_B()
0.83216986999392528
```

Answer (score 1):

The simples way I can think of with the information provided would be to abstract the generation of x to a
new function. Something like this:

```
def gen_x():
    x = []
    # your code here
    return x

def func_a(x):
    # your code here
    return x

def func_b(x):
    # your code here
    return x


x = gen_x()
func_a(x)
func_b(x)
```

Another option could be that func_a returns a tuple with x and the result of your current func_a. Then you could pass the x generated at func_a to func_b